# Show records common to two active record queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a search function in my rails app, where a user can be searched for by a `game` or a `tag`. Both game and tag `has_and_belong_to_many` users.

I'd like searching for a `game` **and** a `tag` to display only users with both that game and tag.

I could probably filter the results out in the `view` but I think that would still cause the query to run and server load?

Search model:

```
users = User.all

users =
       tu = Tag.includes(:users).where(["name like ?", "%#{user_profile_tag}%"]) 
       gu = Game.includes(:users).where(["name like ?", "%#{game}%"])

    users = (tu + gu)

    return users 

end
```

I'm at a bit of a loss as to what to do, I've tried using `&` between `tu and gu` but for this lists no users.

Searches controller:

```
def new
    @search = Search.new
    @game = User.includes(:game).where(game: { name: @game })
    @user_profile_tag = User.includes(:tag).where(tag: { name: @user_profile_tag })

end
```

Any ideas much appreciated!

Edit: model associations

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :games
has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :users

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

Comment: Use 'joins' instead of 'includes', or use 'includes' and 'references' method too. Also you should post your modelos relationships too

Comment: @arieljuod thanks, have included the models now

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to apply both conditions at the same time?

```
users = User.joins(:games, :tags)
            .where(games: { name: @game }, tags: { name: @user_profile_tag })
```

This should return users who have both game with name `@game` and tag with name `@user_profile_tag`.

Comment: Thanks, this returned a template error: 

`Association named 'game' was not found on User; perhaps you misspelled it?`

Maybe there is an issue with associations? Have edited the original question to include them.

Comment: it's `games`. that is what I meant in my answer. I have updated the answer.